# Hide tray popup menu when user clicks away

Tags: windows, delphi, system-tray

I built a Windows tray icon application in Delphi (with `Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, @idata)`). On right-clicking the tray symbol, an instance of `TPopupMenu` appears. Now when I click away from the application, for example on taskbar or on another application's window, this popup menu doesn't disappear. I checked other tray applications: their popup menus disappear when I click away. How to do that?

**The minimal example**

```
unit TrayPopupDoesNotDisappearMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, Vcl.Forms, Winapi.ShellApi,
  Vcl.Menus, System.Classes;

const
  WM_NOTIFYICON = WM_USER + 333;

type
  TTrayPopupDoesNotDisappearForm = class(TForm)
    TrayPopup: TPopupMenu;
    ExitMenuItem: TMenuItem;
    procedure ExitMenuItemClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure _wmClickIcon(var msg: TMessage); message WM_NOTIFYICON;
  protected
    procedure DoCreate(); override;
  end;

var
  TrayPopupDoesNotDisappearForm: TTrayPopupDoesNotDisappearForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TTrayPopupDoesNotDisappearForm._wmClickIcon(var msg: TMessage);
var
  p: TPoint;
begin
  if msg.LParam = WM_RBUTTONUP then begin
    GetCursorPos(p);
    TrayPopup.Popup(p.X, p.Y);
  end;
end;

procedure TTrayPopupDoesNotDisappearForm.DoCreate();
var
  idata: TNotifyIconData;
begin
  inherited;
  idata.cbSize := SizeOf(TNotifyIconData);
  idata.Wnd := Handle;
  idata.uID := 123;
  idata.uFlags := NIF_MESSAGE or NIF_ICON or NIF_TIP;
  idata.uCallbackMessage := WM_NOTIFYICON;
  idata.hIcon := LoadIcon(MainInstance, 'MAINICON');
  StrLCopy(idata.szTip, PWideChar(Application.Title), 128);
  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, @idata);
end;

procedure TTrayPopupDoesNotDisappearForm.ExitMenuItemClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  idata: TNotifyIconData;
begin
  FillChar(idata, SizeOf(TNotifyIconData), 0);
  idata.cbSize := SizeOf(TNotifyIconData);
  idata.Wnd := Handle;
  idata.uID := 123;
  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, @idata);
  Application.Terminate();
end;

end.
```

Comment: Did you try with TTrayIcon component included with Delphi?

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? ``TTrayIcon`` works like a charm.

Comment: It kinda depends on exactly how you are using `Shell_NotifyIcon`. An [mcve] would show us that. That said, this sounds almost certainly like a well known issue. I've included some duplicates.

Comment: FWIW, my code to show the context menu looks like this `SetForegroundWindow(Handle); NotifyIconPopupMenu.Popup(Point.X, Point.Y); PostMessage(Handle, WM_NULL, 0, 0);` where `Handle` is the main form's window handle. I have a comment referring to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/135788 but that link is dead. Here it is, archived: https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/135788